# My understanding about JDK, JRE and JVM

Tags: java, jvm

After my deep analysis this is how i have understand about JDK, JRE and JVM.
Please correct me if i am wrong...

1. JVM is subset of JRE, JRE is subset of JDK.
2. JVM is used to convert the byte code (*.class) to object code(machine code) by using JRE.
3. JRE has Operating System (OS) specify DLL which is used by JVM for byte code to object code conversion.
4. If suppose tomorrow if any new OS will launch then the currently available JREs may not  support the JVM for byte code to machine code conversion. So the JRE may required to enhance to support for the new upcoming OS.
5. So from the above my analysis i am concluding like JVM is common for all OS but JRE has OS specific DLL which will be used by the JVM during byte code to object code conversion.

Comment: Can you format this so it is a little easier to read?

Comment: Here is the doc, no need to analyze, just read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/

Comment: You seem to be obsessed by "byte code to object code conversion". But the JVM does not need to do that to execute bytecode programs, which is their only task.

Comment: jgitter: sure from next post onwards i will do it, thanks for your comments.

Comment: Vitaly: yes during my analysis i have gone through those docs, in order to get confirmation and get more information from the experts like you i have posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JVM is virtual, you can think of it as a virtual computer whose machine code is the Java bytecode. It is not a real computer but a virtual one which can execute Java bytecode instructions.

JRE is the JVM implementation. The implementation is OS-specific (of course) but it provides OS-independent outer interface (meaning e.g. you can run same Java code on a Windows JRE and on a Linux JRE). This is the 'write-once-run-anywhere' thing from the late 90s.

JDK is the compiler, the JRE, other tools, and all Java APIs you need to write Java code.

I don't want to add Android and its Dalvik VM to the picture (though I can draw some interesting parallels), as I will confuse you more, I think.

Comment: The JVM is not an abstract machine, it is a virtual one. Hence a virtual machine. An abstract machine you can find in academics.

Comment: yes ok ;) that's what i basically meant

Comment: The official definition is that the JRE also includes the Java SE API. It's not just the JVM.

Comment: @Radiodef OK. When you want to teach somebody something, you'd better omit some details initially to avoid distractions/confusions. My purpose was not to copy the official definitions. There's no point in that, they are quite well detailed on the Oracle Java site.

Comment: Fair enough! I just felt the need to point it out I guess.

Comment: @Radiodef Sure, NP, thanks. It's good you pointed it out. Because others (at a different level) could like your note more (as it's more precise, more real-world one).

Answer (score 5):

You're pretty much there.  I'd just suggest the following:

> JVM is subset of JRE, JRE is subset of JDK.

This is fair enough.  The JVM (Java Virtual Machinve) is included with the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) to run bytecode (.class files).  The JRE is included if you download the whole JDK (Java Development Kit), which also includes development tools like the compiler.

> JVM is used to convert the byte code (*.class) to object code(machine code) by using JRE.

Basically, yes.  The JVM executes the bytecode and part of this process involves converting it into machine code.  You need a JDK to compile the .java files (source code) into .class files (bytecode) so that it can be executed on the JVM.

> JRE has Operating System (OS) specify DLL which is used by JVM for byte code to object code conversion.

The JVM, when executing the byte code, has a JIT (just-in-time) compiler that turns the platform-agnostic byte code into platform-specific machine code.  In Windows, this would be included in a DLL, yes.  Also included in the JRE are OS-specific implementations of the native methods, such as those declared in `java.lang.Object`.

> If suppose tomorrow if any new OS will launch then the currently available JREs may not support the JVM for byte code to machine code conversion. So the JRE may required to enhance to support for the new upcoming OS.

Yes, a native implementation of the JVM will be required if it's a brand new operating system.  You may be able to compile the OpenJDK on this new OS, though.

> So from the above my analysis I am concluding like JVM is common for all OS but JRE has OS specific DLL which will be used by the JVM during byte code to object code conversion.

I wouldn't say that the JVM is common to all operating systems, rather that there is a JRE (and therefore JVM) implementation for each mainstream OS.  These OS-native JVMs will make use of libraries that are OS-specific when they execute the OS-agnostic Java byte code.

Answer (score 2):

Let's describe it:

**JVM**: Java Virtual Machine. This is basically an application, a binary which is OS-specific. This binary reads .class files and interprets the bytecode or compiles it to machine code and executes it.

**Java API**: This is a lot of code available to programmers. Basic functions like HashSets, List, etc.. Some of this code may be OS-specific, e.g. java.lang.Math. Most of it is independent and saved as Bytecode

**JRE**: The Java Runtime Environment is bundle of a JVM, the Java API, and some utilities. The complete bundle is OS-specific. It is targeted at people who want to run Java applications

**JDK**: The Java Development Kit is a JRE plus a compiler (source to bytecode) and tools needed for development of Java applications

1. yes
2. no, this is all done by the JVM in the first place
3. no, JVM and JRE contain OS-specific parts
4. yes
5. no

If you are talking about JRE/JDK you should not put it on the same level as JVM.

Comment: Absurd-Mind: You mean JVM is a binary which is part of JRE and it is OS specific? and do you mean there are OS specific JRE (JVM + API + Utilities) bundle?

Comment: Yes, since the JVM is binary it is OS/architecture specific, and so is the JRE because it contains the JVM, binary utilities and parts of the Java APIs which are native

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/index.html#jre-jdk

> **JRE and JDK** Oracle provides two principal software products in the
>   Java™ Platform, Standard Edition (Java™ SE) family:
>
> **Java SE Runtime Environment (JRE)**
>
> The JRE **provides** the libraries, Java virtual machine, and other
>   components necessary for you to run applets and applications written
>   in the Java programming language. This runtime environment can be
>   redistributed with applications to make them free-standing.
>
> **Java SE Development Kit (JDK)**
>
> The JDK **includes** the JRE plus command-line development tools such as
>   compilers and debuggers that are necessary or useful for developing
>   applets and applications.
>
> **Java Virtual Machines**
>
> The Java virtual machine is an **abstract** computing machine that has an
>   instruction set and manipulates memory at run time. The Java virtual
>   machine is ported to different platforms to provide hardware- and
>   operating system-independence.

Often, JVM and an implementation of JVM are used interchangeably. This is acceptable when all parties understand this fact.

Comment: Vitaly: From your post I am not clear about JVM, please provide me more details.

Comment: It clearly says that JVM is an abstract thing, it's a model. JRE provides the implementation of JVM. No more details required at this level. If you want to learn more about JVM here is its specification http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/

Answer (score 0):

**JVM** is the process that is launched by **java.exe** or **javaw.exe** that exists under **bin** folder of the **JRE**. **JRE** is the bundle of necessary binaries to launch a java process. **JRE** is not only OS specific, but also architecture specific.